# Why was Guinan on the Enterprise in "Yesterday's Enterprise?"

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Given that it was a military ship (no families) in that timeline, should Guinan have even been there?

Comment: While excluding families I don't see a reason why being a military ship would preclude non-military roles... You still need medical (even if battle field level and not on-going/respite care) and science (even if not exploratory or purely reserarch based). Presumably you'd still also have personnel to tend bar and cut hair etc...? (plus Guinan's pretty good with a phaser - she nailed Worf on that holodeck game)

Comment: "she nailed Worf on that holodeck game" If the flagship's security officer gets beaten by a wide margin by the ship's bartender, no wonder why then the Enterprise gets boarded and the crew taken hostage every other episode...

Comment: Worf gets routinely "nailed" by **everybody.**  Little old ladies, children, out of shape old men, any one and every one can kick his ass - and **does** kick his ass.

Comment: Don’t insert spaces when searching for tags. Type “StarTrek” (no quotes).

Comment: Of course given how that timeline goes, she shouldn't have met Picard in the 1890s. But then maybe that's why she has such a sense things are wrong...

Comment: Guinan's experience with the Borg may have led her to want to help war refugees, and being on a Federation warship gives her that opportunity.

Answer (score 6):

A deleted line from the [original script](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/163.txt) explains that she's been with him (as a trusted advisor, tactician and confidante) since the year that the war began, e.g. 2344.

> She moves closer to him... and if there is a sense of quiet power from Guinan that seems almost evangelical, it is intended.
>
> **GUINAN:** *Picard, we have been together for twenty-two years. I have been your advisor, your confidant, your friend and in all those twenty-two years, I have never led you astray. This time line cannot be allowed to continue. I've told you what you must do. You have only your faith in me to help you decide.*

As to what she's *doing* on the Warship Enterprise (aside from acting as Picard's sounding board), the answer is that she's running the canteen.

Comment: ... and she runs the cantina because of what happens two seasons later and ~500 years ago as seen in *Time's Arrow*. She's been pulling strings to be exactly where she needs to be for several hundred years.

Comment: "e.g. 2344." i,e,, not e,g,